# Projection of a GPS point on a polyline consisting of other GPS points

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to ask if there is a quite decent way to "project" GPS point to a polyline consisting of other GPS points. The result of this “projection” should be the coordinates of the projected point on the polyline.

I'm looking for something like that(I need GPS coordinates of point red 'X'):

[image: line of gps points]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you build your solution on the function `sf::st_nearest_points()` - it returns the shortest path between two geometry objects as a linestring.

It will accept a point and a line as arguments. The function requires its arguments to be projected (so no lat / lon - but it is easy to reproject the result back to WGS84).

As the function returns linestring it is necessary to `sf::st_cast()` it to point geometry type to get the start and end of the line.

As your example is not easily reproducible I am demonstrating the approach on a somewhat convoluted example of a geocoded address in Prague and the closest point on the Vltava river. The river as a line and geocoding function are from package RCzechia, and are completely unrelated to your problem.

What you require is a line and a point, both in a projected coordinate reference system.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(RCzechia) # Czech spatial objects to have some data to work with...

# an address in Prague
free_point <- RCzechia::geocode("pplk. Sochora 4, Praha 7") %>% 
  filter(typ == "AdresniMisto") %>% 
  st_transform(5514) #↨a local projected CRS


# a piece of river (to have a linestring)
vltava <- RCzechia::reky() %>% 
  filter(NAZEV == "Vltava") %>% 
  st_transform(5514) %>%  #↨a local projected CRS
  st_intersection(sf::st_buffer(free_point, 2500)) %>% # a buffer of 2500 meters around point
  st_geometry() %>% 
  st_union() %>% 
  st_line_merge()

# the interesting part starts here!!!

# a line from address to the closest point on the river
closest_line <- st_nearest_points(st_geometry(vltava),
                                  st_geometry(free_point)) 

# start of the line - this is what I seek :)
closest_point <- st_cast(closest_line, to = "POINT")[1]

# report results
plot(st_geometry(vltava))
plot(free_point, pch = 4, col = "red", add = T)
plot(closest_point, pch = 4, col = "blue", add = T)
```

[image: points in Prague]

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, I have a dataframe with GPS points of polyline and one GPS point which I want to project on this line - want to find nearest point on polyline from this point. But I think I found the solution using dist2Line function.